# How to write Xamarin.Android output to windows text file?

Tags: debugging, xamarin.forms, io, root

I am using Xamarin Forms and I want to output some debug information into a file that I want to be created in the .Net Standard bin directory in Windows so I can open it. However, since I am debugging with an Android Phone I can seemingly only create files inside the data directory on the phone which I do not have access to. The reason I am trying to do this is because I do not have root access to my phone and rooting it has failed, so I need to create the file on windows to be able to see its contents.

Basically I am trying to print the contents of my sqlite database to a file on my windows desktop since I cannot browse the database directly as I do not have root access on my phone which I have tried to get (using KingoRoot) but failed.

Comment: You can't do this.  Android has no concept of the Windows file system.  You can write to the log using Console.Writeline statements, which you can view in the Application Output window at runtime, or view later using the Android tools

Comment: @Jason I understand that Android has no concept of the Windows file system, however I am imagining a way in which Visual Studio may retrieve values from the phone to output them into a file. I believe this must be possible since Visual Studio can also output it into stdout or console so why not in a file?